PHP Laravel How to save mail in folders as HTML files
I want to save sent emails in /storage/maildump.
the folder is created and if I try to send mail the folder stays empty.
mail.php looks like:
  'mailers' => [

        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'url' => env('MAIL_URL'),
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 2525),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN', parse_url(env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'), PHP_URL_HOST)),
            'log' => [
              'transport' => 'file',
              'path' => storage_path('maildump'),
            ],

        ],

I'm not sure why this isn't working.

So basically, instead of using HTML files, you'll be using blade files. You can save these files anywhere inside the resources/views directory. According to the docs, you can create a resources/views/emails directory to keep all your email templates, or you can put them wherever you want inside the resources/views directory.
For more info about blade files related to your mail, you can check it out here. Laravel also offers markdown mail if you prefer that.
